# Django proper way to save global API client instance variable

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, singleton

How to store some API client instance and make it available across the whole project.

`API client instance` - is some `AppApi()` and I need to call it's methods in different views (and even apps) from whole django project.

As for me, there are two ways:

1. create a global variable in some core django app `core/apps.py` module;
2. create singleton wrapper;

What is the best and proper way to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `django.db.connections`, `django.db.router`, `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.staticfiles_storage` and there's a few more out there. Basically, you create a module variable that has the instance of your singleton class and then import that variable:

```py
from django.db import connections

vendor = connections['default'].vendor  # always the same during app lifetime.
```